# Random pieces of screen are being rendered opengl- what error does this indicate?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm playing around with openGL (3.3 on OSX Mavericks), and I'm getting random parts of my screen being rendered to my window. I'm assuming that's probably clear evidence that I'm doing SOMETHING wrong... but what? Is it something with uninitialized values in a buffer? Am I using a buffer I didn't create? Some weird memory management thing? Or something like that?

Sorry if the question is a bit vague- I'm just betting that this is one of those bugs that openGL vets will hear and go "Of course! That means that {insert thing I'm doing wrong}".

Here's a screen shot to get an idea for what I'm talking about: [image: error]

the black circle is what I'm attempting to render, the upside-down google logo is what I don't understand. Also, every time I run it I get different random textures.

Thanks! And I'd be happy to supply more details, I just don't know what other relevant info to include...

Comment: Sounds like you're not properly clearing the color buffer. Also, how is your pixel format setup (e.g. single- or double-buffered, any alpha bits)?

Comment: oh gosh duh. thanks a ton! I was clearing the default buffer's color/depth bits, and I was rendering to a texture and then displaying that texture without clearing THAT framebuffer's color/depth. Thanks again!

Comment: @Andon/Phildo: You should post that as an answer ;)

Comment: @KromStern - is there a way to do that while giving credit to andon?

Comment: @Phildo: He did not posted it, so I assume he is fine with just being helpful without putting too much effort into it. After all those reputation points are quite virtual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Andon M. Coleman (in the comments above), I've realized that this was simply a result of me not properly clearing the color buffer.

Specifically, my pipeline involved me rendering to a texture, and then blitting that texture to the screen. I WAS correctly clearing the SCREENS color buffer, but I never cleared the intermediate FB's color buffer.